# How to use SIGRTMIN in x86 or armeabi-v7a abi in Android NDK?

Tags: android, linux, android-ndk, pthreads, signals

I am trying to use **SIGRTMIN** signal to create blocking signalhandler in Android NDK.

```
int startThread(){
   pthread_t thread;
   sigset_t set;

       /* Block SIGRTMIN other threads created by main()
          will inherit a copy of the signal mask. */

   sigemptyset(&set);
   int rc = sigaddset(&set, SIGRTMIN);
   __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_DEBUG, "LOG", "Return Code:%d",rc);
   __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_DEBUG, "LOG", "Error Code:%d",errno);
   pthread_sigmask(SIG_BLOCK, &set, NULL);
   pthread_create(&thread, NULL, &sig_thread, (void *) &set);
}

static void *sig_thread(void *arg)
{
   sigset_t *set = arg;
   int s, sig;
   for (;;) {
       s = sigwait(set, &sig);

       __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_DEBUG, "LOG", "Signal handling thread got signal %d\n", sig);
   }
}
```

I am getting Return Code as -1 and Error code as 22 (**EINVAL - Invalid Argument**) while adding signal set `sigaddset(&set, SIGRTMIN)`

This is happening in `x86` or `armeabi-v7a` abi. If i use `x86_64` then it works.

is there any way to solve this problem or any alternative in `x86/armeabi-v7a` abi in Android?

Comment: Are you using an old NDK by any chance? `SIGRTMIN` used to be a constant that would get baked into your application that wouldn't necessarily be correct on new versions of Android. It's since been changed to be a function (with an as correct as possible fallback for pre-L API levels), but if you're using an old NDK it's possible that you have a bad definition of `SIGRTMIN` for your device.

Comment: I am using latest NDK Tool 18.1 and Android 8.0 and 7.0